# Gremlin set property operations

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have below mentioned dataset

`g.addV('testvertex').property(id, 'user1').property(set, 'states','TX').property(set,'states','CA').property(set,'states','AL').property(set,'states','AK')`

1. how do I find the count of states 'user1' has lived in?
2. if 'user1' ever lived in 'IA' and 'KS' ?
3. how do i drop 'TX' from states set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I find the count of states 'user1' has lived in?

```
g.V().values('states').count()
```

> if 'user1' ever lived in 'IA' and 'KS' ?

```
g.V().has(id,'user1').has('states', within('IA','KS'))
```

> how do i drop 'TX' from states set ?

```
g.V().has(id,'user1').
  properties('states').hasValue('TX').drop()
```